# Websocket remove old or specific frames

Tags: websocket, autobahn, ratchet

I am using websockets via Autobahn library (http://autobahn.ws/js/) and PHP Ratchet websocket server.

For now I am sending a fairly big amount of data through websockets therefore I want to have a way to remove old or specific frames for control over consumed memory.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is this for the Autobahn or the Rachet side of things?

Comment: for Autobahn, not to consume browser resources on a slow machine